# Moving Document Library from one site to another - Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, list-template, move

Let me start by stating that the 2 sites are within the same Sharepoint, but not within the same Site Collection. I did not create any of the sites, nor did I perform any kind of document management ever before. This in fact my first work on this project and I am very new to Sharepoint.

The client has a document library which consists of thousands of document sets, which consist of hundreds of thousands of documents. My task is to move/copy the whole document library to a newly created site.

Site1: accessible from: name.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Home.aspx
Site2: accessible from: name.sharepoint.com/sites/DocumentManagement

What I tried:

1. Create the whole Document Library as a template without the content. Then move the single Document Sets using the 'Send To'. Problem here is that when I select the document set, the 'Send to' option is grayed out. When I try to create the document set as a template from the library settings, the settings that I managed to access were the document library settings so creating that template as an app would actually be re-creating the document library and not the document set: which is not what I want. So the only remaining way I could think of in this option, would be to manually create the document set in the document library on site 2, and move the document items from within the document set of site 1 using the 'Send to'. Again, the problem here is that I still cannot choose more than 1 document item at a time, and this is clearly not an option for over 100,000 documents in thousands of document sets.
2. Create the whole document library including the content. The problem here is that the content option is grayed out and cannot be selected. This option, had it been available, would have created the layout of the document library with all its subsequent columns, the document sets and the documents within.
3. Use the Content and Structure option in Site Settings. This apparently only works if the sites are within the same site collection, which is not applicable in my case.
4. From the Office 365 Admin Panel, further into Sharepoint Admin, I tried creating a 'Send to connection' from the 'records management' section. I went into the Site Settings - Site Administration - Content Organizer Settings of Site 2 and obtained the 'Send to url' from there. This does not work on the document library. Neither does it work on the document set. The 'Send to connection' I created (called 'invoices') does not appear as shown in the screenshot.

[image: See screenshot]

Finally when trying to use this method on a single document item, the Send to connection can be seen and it does work on some single items, on some others the options are just not there. I have no idea what could be the different in this scenario?! But still, it is not useful for me as when selecting more than 1 item, the 'Send to' option is grayed out and again I can't imagine doing over 100,000 item like this one at a time.

5. I am considering a workflow/code option, but I dont know from where to start, being so new to this area. In this case, I would appreciate if someone can set me on the right route. Some code I can start with or an article/tutorial I can follow.

Finally, excuse my long post but I thought this was the best way to describe my issue and the long hours I spent trying to get around it. I would appreciate any input regarding the whole problem or even the 1-5 points I mentioned up here ^.

Comment: do you want to just move documents or its metadata like created date,author too?

Comment: you can use sharegate tool(trial) to move whole document library. but i am not sure about size limit in trial copy.

Comment: Hi Anil pal. Thank you for commenting. I want to move all the content, metadata as well as the column layout of both the document library and the document sets. With regards to the Sharegate Tool (trial), I am not sure that a trial will be sufficient for more than 100,000 documents. I was hoping to explore a code/workflow way of doing this. Any help?

Comment: How many column library has and what is datatype of each column?

Comment: 9 columns, Name, DateCreated, Version, ClientNo, TaxNo, Content Type, Shared With, etc

Answer (score 1):

Try to take help of Microsoft support team.

OR

I would suggest to use sharegate trial and move items in batches e.g(1000*100).

if batches will be small error will be less.

OR

you can try below step

It is difficult to make 100% replica and code will become lengthy.

1. Create template (without content) and upload to destination site.
2. Create library using this template.
3. Now read created list using CSOM.
4. Upload files and update its metadata(other columns) using CSOM.
5. Update file version using CSOM.
6. update permission of list and list item using CSOM.

Limitation: you will face issue with lookup column.

To start you can check below link

https://nasironline.wordpress.com/tag/move-document-library-items-using-client-object-model/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d068230a-3b95-4a1d-926c-292af2b20b5e/programmatically-move-file-with-sharepoint-2010-managed-client-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. I am considering attempting the last option but I would appreciate some extra help about getting started. What do I need to create? I am finding problems with creating sharepoint projects in visual studio, be it Sharepoint Apps or Empty Projects. I would find a tutorial or an article about this most useful

Comment: Do you even need to create a Sharepoint project ? Do you need workflows? Point me in the right direction and Ill take it from there! Thanks again :)

Comment: you can create console application on server, since you want to move document sets.

Comment: Try to make Powershell script, it would be better option

Answer (score 0):

I have also been in the similar situation. And believe me when it comes to large amount of data migration within SharePoint components, We need to rely on 3rd part Tools. I have migrated around 8000+ documents to another site collection's document  library.

I used Content Matrix migration tool - SP Edition by Metalogix and it worked superfine for me. Refer below:
[image]

Comment: I am using paid version of content matrix tool